# Rate of change for circular function

Tags: calculus

My Question:

A large sheet of ice in the shape of a circle, has an initial radius of 350 miles. If the ice shrinks at the rate of 1.5 miles per year, determine the rate at which the ice is shrinking.

My answer:

$$A = \pi r^2$$
$$A=\pi r [T]^2$$
$$\frac{da}{dt} = \frac {\pi d[r(T)]^2}{d(T)}$$ 
$$\pi \cdot 2r (T) \cdot r(T)$$
$$\pi \cdot 2 \cdot 350 \cdot 1.5 = 1050 \pi$$
$$1050 \pi \frac {miles^2}{year}$$

Could someone check my answer please. And let me know if i have gone wrong, and where. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say you've gone wrong, exactly, but it seems like a couple pieces are missing from your question. 
You've given the prompt as "If the ice shrinks at the rate of 1.5 miles per year, determine the rate at which the ice is shrinking." From your work it looks like you've interpreted this to mean "If the RADIUS of the ice shrinks at the rate of 1.5 miles per year", which is an assumption supported by units involved. 
However, it is unclear if the question is then asking for the INITIAL rate of change for the area of the entire ice sheet (which you found) or the general rate of change of the area of the ice sheet, which will be variable! If a radius is shrinking constantly, the area will change more and more rapidly as the radius shrinks, thus the solution would have to be a function in terms of T or r. In order to determine whether your solutions works, you need to be clearer about what the question is looking for.